# Replace missing values with the values from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have 4 variables in my dataset, for example

```
treatment_alone = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No")
treatment_and_fertilizer = c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No")
treatment_and_manure = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")
treatment_and_composte = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")

data_test = data.frame(treatment_alone, treatment_and_fertilizer, treatment_and_manure,
                       treatment_and_composte)
```

I would like to create a new column where all these variables are in one column as a categorical variable by replacing their "No" values with "Yes" values of other columns: for example,

```
treatment (treatment_alone, treatment_and_fertilizer, treatment_and_manure, treatment_and_compost)
```

I tried the following code to make it work

```
df = data_test %>%
treatment_alone = ifelse(treatment_alone == "Yes","treatment alone",""),
    treatment_and_fertilizer = ifelse(treatment_and_fertilizer == "Yes","treatment and fertilizer",""),
    treatment_and_manure = ifelse(treatment_and_manure == "Yes","treatment and manure",""),
    treatment_and_compost = ifelse(treatment_and_compost == "Yes","treatment and compost","")

df = data_test %>%
  mutate(treatment = coalesce(treatment_alone,treatment_and_fertilizer, treatment_and_manure, treatment_and_compost))
```

But it did not work. I also tried to replace the values from two columns as follows

```
df = data_test %>%
  mutate(treatment = coalesce(treatment_alone,treatment_and_fertilizer))
```

Also did not work. Does anyone know how to create such a column by replacing "No" values with "Yes"?

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide reproducible example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may not need to create new columns - if the column names are all starting with `treatment`, loop `across` those columns, replace the `"Yes"` with the column name (`cur_column()`) after replacing the `_` with space (`str_replace_all`) and `invoke` the list of columns output with `coalesce` (Note that when we don't specify the `TRUE` condition in `case_when`, by default it returns `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   mutate(treatment = invoke(coalesce, across(starts_with("treatment"), 
     ~ case_when(.x == "Yes"~ str_replace_all(cur_column(), "_", " ")))))
```

---

The issue in the OP's code seems to be assigning `no` case in `ifelse` to `""`.  `coalesce` would select the first non-NA in each row, thus if it is blank, it wouldn't have any effect

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this code but it did work it did not work, it created a biochar variable with values NA only

Comment: @madina_b I get `data_test %>%
   mutate(treatment = invoke(coalesce, across(starts_with("treatment"), 
     ~ case_when(.x == "Yes"~ str_replace_all(cur_column(), "_", " "))))) %>% pull(treatment)#[1] "treatment alone"          "treatment and fertilizer" "treatment alone"          "treatment and fertilizer" "treatment and manure"    
[6] "treatment and composte"   "treatment and manure"     "treatment and composte"`